How to have multiple EvergineView in one page?
I have an issue with having multiple Evergine View In the same Page In Maui App. Every time I tried, I get an Exception thrown. For good measure, I tried it with the EverSneaks project, from Evergine devs.
Here are the XAML changes (SneakersDetailsView.xaml):
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <evergine:EvergineView x:Name="evergineView0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Image
                     Grid.Column="0"
                    Source="black_heart.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource HeartStyle}" />

                <evergine:EvergineView x:Name="evergineView1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Image
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Source="black_heart.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource HeartStyle}" />
            </Grid>

The CodeBehind changes (SneakersDetailsView.xaml.cs):
public partial class SneakersDetailsView : ContentPage
{
    public SneakersDetailsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.evergineView0.Application = new MyApplication();
        this.evergineView1.Application = new MyApplication();


        this.BindingContext = new SneakersDetailsViewModel(this.evergineView0, this.evergineView1);
    }
    
    // Unchanged methods
}

And here are the ViewModel changes (SneakersDetailsViewModel.cs):
public class SneakersDetailsViewModel
{
    public ICommand ColorCommand { get; set; }

    private EvergineView evergineView0;
    private EvergineView evergineView1;

    private ControllerService controllerService0;
    private ControllerService controllerService1;

    public SneakersDetailsViewModel(EvergineView evergineView0, EvergineView evergineView1)
    {
        this.evergineView0 = evergineView0;
        this.controllerService0 = this.evergineView0.Application.Container.Resolve<ControllerService>();

        this.evergineView1 = evergineView1;
        this.controllerService1 = this.evergineView1.Application.Container.Resolve<ControllerService>();

        this.ColorCommand = new Command<string>(
            (color) =>
            {
                switch (color)
                {
                    case "red":
                        this.controllerService0.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Red;
                        this.controllerService1.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Red;
                        break;
                    case "orange":
                        this.controllerService0.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Orange;
                        this.controllerService1.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Orange;
                        break;
                    case "blue":
                        this.controllerService0.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Blue;
                        this.controllerService1.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Blue;
                        break;
                    case "gray":                            
                    default:
                        this.controllerService0.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Gray;
                        this.controllerService1.Color = ControllerService.SneakerColor.Gray;
                        break;
                }                    
                
            });
    }
}

The exception thrown depends on the Evergine version.
With version 2024.10.24.7, I get an Evergine.Framwork.Exceptions.BindingException: [GraphicsPresenter].graphicsContext Failed resolving [GraphicsContext] in MyApplication.Initialize()
With version 2024.6.28.10, I get a System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name in ControllerService.Start()
It seems to work fine when using multiple EvergineView in the app but with only one per page.
I'm aware to not use the static field Application.Current, since it get overwritten every time when instantiating a new EvergineView, which can cause unpredictable behavior.

What's the namespace of the EvergineView? I can't create it in my project.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT namespace EverSneaks.MAUI.Evergine, for simplicity i have used the Eversneaks project from the Evergine devs to reproduce this issue

We just got an update for the Evergine Engine, and the Exception raised is now Evergine.Framework.Exceptions.BindingException, ill continue to investigate and ill update the post accordingly
